# terminal command from Python in OS X

Tags: macos, python-3.x

Is there a good way to differentiate between OS implementation errors (I'm thinking about OSX's shipped version of python) vs a general error?

Is this raising an exception because it's clearly an Apple/OSX specific command and outside of normal script commands that subprocess.call expects?

If so, how should I get python to mimic the behavior of my typing that command out in terminal?

```
subprocess.call("defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES")
```

Comment: [Not a shell command.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/defaults.1.html)

Comment: How does what you already have fail?

Comment: If it is a script, surely it doesn't matter whether the Finder shows hidden files or not  - your script will still see the hidden files regardless of what the Finder displays to the user. Also, try putting the full path for the `defaults` program, i.e. `subprocess.call("/usr/bin/defaults write ...")`. Also, you need to restart the Finder for the setting to take effect, so you need `subprocess.call("/usr/bin/defaults write...   && killall Finder")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this command to edit plists via python (in this case, the Munki MangedInstalls.plist):

```
subprocess.call(' /usr/bin/defaults write /Library/Preferences/ManagedInstalls InstallAppleSoftwareUpdates 1 ', shell=True)
```

And this command to read the same plist:

```
os.popen(' /usr/bin/defaults read /Library/Preferences/ManagedInstalls InstallAppleSoftwareUpdates ').read()
```

(I realize this thread is a few months old but figured I would post this incase anyone is looking for this information in the future.)